# Unable to visit the Invoice Ninja page

Tags: docker, invoice-ninja

I used a dockerfile to deploy [Invoice Ninja](https://www.invoiceninja.com/)，but I am unable to access the Invoice Ninja page。

I attempt to visit the url: http://ninja.example.de:8080/, but the content is the [Caddy page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqf06.png).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  server:
    image: caddy:alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_URL=http://ninja.example.de
    volumes:
      # Vhost configuration
      #- ./config/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - ./public:/var/invoiceninja/public
      - ./storage:/var/invoiceninja/storage
    depends_on:
      - app
    # Run webserver nginx on port 80
    # Feel free to modify depending what port is already occupied
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    #  - "443:443"
    networks:
      - invoiceninja

  app:
    image: invoiceninja/invoiceninja
    restart: always
    environment:
      - APP_URL=ninja.example.de
      - APP_KEY=base64:Iczfntb0PgJImdMW6PxMDeHi/v/h82yKv5xeYX3QvpU=
      - MULTI_DB_ENABLED=false
      - DB_HOST1=db
    volumes:  
      - ./public:/var/invoiceninja/public
      - ./storage:/var/invoiceninja/storage
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - invoiceninja

  db:
    image: mysql:5
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - MYSQL_USER=ninja
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ninja
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db-ninja-01
    volumes:  
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - invoiceninja

 # cron:
 # cron is commented out by me

volumes:
  mysql-data:
  public:
  storage:

networks:
  invoiceninja:
```

the docker-compose logs result:  I cann't see the error
[image]

Comment: @codedge hello，Can you help me ?  thank you

Comment: There are now [guides](https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles/wiki) available which describe step by step how to set up IN. Furthermore I see that you mix env vars for IN 4 with one of IN 5. See differences [here](https://github.com/invoiceninja/dockerfiles/wiki/differences-version-4-and-5).

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem.
You have to update a line in the Caddyfile to:

```
# Set this path to your site's directory.
root * /var/www/app/public
```

I did that by uncommenting this line and editing the file:

```
./config/caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```

Now, I'm using Docker for Windows and it kept crashing saying I'm trying to find a folder to a file or vice-versa.
So I just made the file myself and copied the contents from the container.

FYI, my original/default file looked like this:

```
# The Caddyfile is an easy way to configure your Caddy web server.
#
# Unless the file starts with a global options block, the first
# uncommented line is always the address of your site.
#
# To use your own domain name (with automatic HTTPS), first make
# sure your domain's A/AAAA DNS records are properly pointed to
# this machine's public IP, then replace the line below with your
# domain name.
:80

# Set this path to your site's directory.
root * /usr/share/caddy

# Enable the static file server.
file_server

# Another common task is to set up a reverse proxy:
# reverse_proxy localhost:8080

# Or serve a PHP site through php-fpm:
# php_fastcgi localhost:9000

# Refer to the Caddy docs for more information:
# https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile
```